# updateOrCreate too slow on thousand data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I do have a problem with updateOrCreate built in function of Laravel as I do have a button that runs these function manually. So problem is if I run it, it always run too slow and sometimes causing it to crash the browser and could be more slower if the data increases each time

```
public function updateDailyCounters()
{
    $key_name = 'some key';
    $article_scores = Redis::hgetall($key_name); // thousands of data

    foreach ($article_scores as $key => $value) {
        $article = Article::whereUuid($key)->first();

        DailyViews::updateOrCreate([
            "view_date" => $score_date, // some date
            "uuid" => $key
        ],[
            "views" => $value
        ]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Since you're using Redis already, why not queue up this operation and let it run independently of the browser? You could create a BulkCreateOrUpdateJob and dispatch that each time this operation needs done.

Comment: I see, I haven't learned queing in Laravel yet. I will check it out.

Comment: This will be quite slow are performing 2 queries for each loop. What do you use `$article` for inside the loop?

Comment: @RossWilson I forgot to remove em. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that updateOrCreate creates thouthands of MYSQL request that freezes database.

Try ::Upserts, it will increase performance skyrockets. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) advice it for amount of lines more that one.

In your example it will look like that:

```
public function updateDailyCounters()
{
    $key_name = 'some key';
    $article_scores = Redis::hgetall($key_name); // thousands of data

    $dataToUpdateOrCreate = [];
    $columnsToUpdate = ['view_date','uuid','views'];
    $dataCheck=['views'];

    foreach ($article_scores as $key => $value) {
        
        $article = Article::whereUuid($key)->first();

        dataToUpdateOrCreate[] = [
            "view_date" => $score_date, // some date
            "uuid" => $key,
            "views" => $value
        ];

    }

    DailyViews::upserts($dataToUpdateOrCreate,$dataCheck,$columnsToUpdate);


}
```